# StructureMap Web API conflicts in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap

I had an ASP.NET MVC 5 app already using StructureMap for dependency resolution in its controllers. After adding the apps first API controller, I installed the StructureMap.WebApi2 NuGet package to get extend dependency resolution to the API controllers. After the installation I got the following error when running the app...

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

Line 46:         {
Line 47:             foreach (var task in
Line 48:                    StructuremapMvc.StructureMapDependencyScope.CurrentNestedContainer.GetAllInstances())
Line 49:             {
Line 50:                 task.Execute();

To test I comment out the following  lines of code from my StructureMapScopeModule class:

```
private void Context_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //foreach (var task in StructuremapMvc.StructureMapDependencyScope.CurrentNestedContainer.GetAllInstances<IRunOnError>())
        //{
        //    task.Execute();
        //}
    }

    private void OnContextOnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //foreach (var task in
        //       StructuremapMvc.StructureMapDependencyScope.CurrentNestedContainer.GetAllInstances<IRunAfterEachRequest>())
        //{
        //    task.Execute();
        //}

        HttpContextLifecycle.DisposeAndClearAll();
        StructuremapMvc.StructureMapDependencyScope.DisposeNestedContainer();

    }
```

When those lines were removed the errors went away and I was able to properly use my new API class. Nothing else has broken in the app that I can see. However that section of code was written by a previous developer and I'm hesitant about removing code when I don't know what is original purpose was.

Can anyone tell me what the intended purpose of those lines could have been, or if their is another solution other than deleting them?